# Concat Dataframes based on keys In Dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
d1_key = "A"
d1 = pd.DataFrame({"A" : [1], "B" : [2]})
d2_key = "B"
d2 = pd.DataFrame({"A" : [3], "B" : [4]})
d3_key = "B"
d3 = pd.DataFrame({"A" : [5], "B" : [6]})
d4_key = "A"
d4 = pd.DataFrame({"A" : [7], "B" : [8]})
```

I have number of dfs with their keys I concat them based on their keys.

Expected Output:

```
{'A':    
    A  B
 0  1  2
 1  7  8,
 'B':    
    A  B
 0  3  4
 1  5  6}
```

Comment: Are the dataframes always one row?

Comment: It's not possible to do something like that with your code. How to determine the pairs (d1_key, d1), (d2_key, d2)...? Except create this intermediate datastructure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### easy solution (works with any number of rows):

```
keys = [d1_key, d2_key, d3_key, d4_key]
dfs  = [d1, d2, d3, d4]

out = {k:g.reset_index(drop=True)
       for k,g in pd.concat(dfs, keys=keys).groupby(level=0)}
```

##### previous answer using a custom Series

Assuming your input dataframes have a single row, you could `concat` and `groupby` to split:

```
keys = [d1_key, d2_key, d3_key, d4_key]
dfs  = [d1, d2, d3, d4]

out = {k: g.reset_index(drop=True)
       for k,g in pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True).groupby(pd.Series(keys))}
```

output:

```
{'A':    A  B
 0  1  2
 1  7  8,
 'B':    A  B
 0  3  4
 1  5  6}
```

If your input dataframes have more than one row, you need to account for the length when building the grouping Series:

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame({"A" : [1,9], "B" : [2,10]})

import numpy as np
group = pd.Series(np.repeat(keys, list(map(len,dfs))))
```

Example (assuming df1 has 2 rows):

```
0    A
1    A
2    B
3    B
4    A
dtype: object
```

Grouping:

```
group = pd.Series(np.repeat(keys, list(map(len,dfs))))

out = {k: g.reset_index(drop=True)
       for k,g in pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True).groupby(group)}
```

output:

```
{'A':    A   B
 0  1   2
 1  9  10
 2  7   8,
 'B':    A  B
 0  3  4
 1  5  6}
```

Answer (score 2):

Let us try

```
df = pd.concat([d1,d2,d3,d4])
df.index = [d1_key,d2_key,d3_key,d4_key]
out = {x : y.reset_index(drop=True) for x, y in df.groupby(level=0)}
out['A']
Out[286]: 
   A  B
0  1  2
1  7  8
```